# fpdf why does it create a new page for every cell?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to create an invoice with fpdf and if it reaches the bottom I want the content to go forward on the next page. So for example I used this code to print lines to go on to the next page.

```
$y = 150;
for($i = 0;$i < 50;$i++) {
$pdf->setXY(150,$y);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'Inclusief BTW: ');
$y += 5;
}
```

Here it it will go down fine as I expect.
[image: It will go all the way down]
But on the second page it shows once.
[image: Shows on the second page but only once]
Also 23 pages are created for every cell 1 page is used and I want it to continue on the second page the same way it does for the first page.

Full code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
test();
function test() {
  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->addPage();
    $y = 5;
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);

    for($i = 0;$i < 150;$i++) {
      $pdf->setXY(10,$y);
      $pdf->Cell(10,10,"Inclusief BTW",0,1);
    $y += 5;

    }
  $pdf->output();
}
?>
```

Comment: You dont' need to setFont` each loop cycle, also check FPDF docs for [Cell](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) and cosinder using `ln` attribute set to 1

Comment: I tried this but no luck it still produces the same output.

Comment: Please provide your full code

Comment: That is pretty much my full code besides the constructor call and pdf output.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the code you shared here is not producing that error

Comment: I edited my post and included the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
$pdf->setXY(10,$y);
for($i = 0;$i < 150;$i++) {
    $pdf->Cell(5, 5, "Inclusief BTW", 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunate this is not working aswell. Does it work for you? if so can you show?

Comment: With your code it was creating 98 pages, with this edit it is now creating just 3 pages. Be sure to put `setXY` outside the loop

Comment: Thanks your right I also had to change 1 into 2 but now it works fine thank you.